Give an example of a 3-form that is not a product of a 1-form and a 2-form.
I am interested in exhibiting $\omega \in \Lambda ^3 ((\mathbb R ^n)^*)$ such that $\omega$ is not the product of a 1-form and a 2-form.
I have a hunch that $\sum_{1<i<j<k<5} \mathrm{d}x_i \wedge \mathrm d x_j \wedge \mathrm d x_k$ might work in $\mathbb R^5$, but I do not know of a nice way to go about showing this.

If $\omega = \alpha \wedge \beta$, where $\alpha$ is a $1$-form and $\beta$ is a $2$-form, then $\alpha \wedge \omega = (\alpha \wedge \alpha) \wedge \beta = 0$.
If $\alpha = f_1 \,\mathrm dx_1 + \dots + f_n\,\mathrm dx_n$, then $\alpha\wedge \omega = f_1(\mathrm dx_1 \wedge \omega) + \dots + f_n(\mathrm dx_n \wedge \omega)$. This is a linear dependence on the set $\{\mathrm dx_1 \wedge \omega, \dots, \mathrm dx_n \wedge \omega\}$, so all we have to do to find a counterexample is find some $\omega$ for which this set is linearly independent.
(Sort of; "linear independent" is maybe not quite the right term, because the coefficients are not a field? The idea is the same, though.)
I think taking $\omega = \mathrm dx_1 \wedge \mathrm dx_2 \wedge \mathrm dx_3 + \mathrm dx_4 \wedge \mathrm dx_5 \wedge \mathrm dx_6$ is a simple example of this. The set $\{\mathrm dx_1 \wedge \omega, \dots, \mathrm dx_n \wedge \omega\}$ is, up to signs, the set $\{d_{1456}, d_{2456}, d_{3456}, d_{1234}, d_{1235}, d_{1236}\}$ where $d_{ijkl}$ stands for $\mathrm dx_i \wedge \mathrm dx_j \wedge \mathrm dx_k \wedge \mathrm dx_l$. There is definitely no nontrivial linear combination of these that adds up to $0$.

There's no need to go to six dimensions to see this. Simply $\text{dxdydz}+\text{dydzdw}$ should do the trick.

It might be worth noting that every 3-form over $\mathbb R^3$ decomposes as a product of a 1 and 2-form quite trivially. So dimension 4 or higher is necessary.

@Snared What if we multiply that by $dx + dw$? (Actually, I think your example factors as $dx + dw$ times $dy,dz$.)

Ah you're right about that. I'm not sure if there is a simple example in 4 dimensions but your logic is tight on the 6-dimension one. Though I'm not sure what the product with $dx+dw$, giving $\pm dx dy dz dw$, necessarily shows?

The product with $dx + dw$ shows that my approach to proving that it doesn't factor wouldn't work. (It doesn't prove that it factors, of course.) In fact, my approach can't possibly work in 4 dimensions, because it requires at least as many independent 4-forms as 1-forms to exist. (I'm pretty sure it works in 5 dimensions, and that it proves that the example given in the question is not factorable, but that's harder to check.)

In 4D, 3-forms are dual to 1-forms (more properly to vectors), hence all 3-forms must be simple. In general this is a geometric question: do $k$ 3D subspaces always share a common line? In 5D, for $k=2$ the answer is "yes". So let's start with $dx\wedge(dy\wedge dz + dw\wedge du)$. The 2-form part cannot be factored, so it suffices to exhibit a 3-form which does not have $dx$ as a factor. This is easy, so we see that $$dx\wedge(dy\wedge dz + dw\wedge du) + dy\wedge dw\wedge dz$$ is a 3-form which is not a product of a 1-form and a 2-form. The answer to the question is "no" for $k=3$.

@Snared $$(dx+dw)\wedge(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz + dy\wedge dz\wedge dw) = (dx+dw)\wedge(dx+dw)\wedge dy\wedge dz = 0.$$

@NicholasTodoroff Ah, yes, sorry, I miscounted the number of swaps when expanding: $(x+w)(xyz+yzw)=xxyz + xyzw + wxyz + wyzw=0 + xyzw - xyzw + 0 = 0$. Here I'm using the notation where letters are implied to have a $d$ preceding them, and concatenation denotes wedging.
